# How to extract data from table which have number in class?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath

In following code I write to extract data from table

with xpath I get names but price class attribute is The number increasing

```
 <td id="f_4142_39_pr"></td> , <td id="f_4139_39_pr"></td> , <td id="f_4136_39_pr"></td> ,...
```

and I can't get all prices

following is [قیمت روز گوشی موبایل](http://priceha.ir/tag/%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2-%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C/) my code

```
$produsttitleQuery = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='entry entryltr'] ");
   $produstpriceQuery = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='f_4136_39_pr']");


 $data = array();   
   $data = array();
   for ($x=0; $x<20; $x++){
    $data[$x]['title'] = $produsttitleQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
    $data[$x]['price'] = $produstpriceQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
   }


echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

--

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Dell 5537 
            [price] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Dell 3521
            [price] => 
        )
,...
```

question 2: I want use foreach loop instead for in top code..

Comment: ..............? @Adrian Cid Almague

Comment: the html from you can obtain the prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had PHP supported XPath 2.0, you could have used the `matches()` function, but PHP supports only XPath 1.0 so that is not an option here. In your case the HTML seems rather fixed, so you could get the price by referring to it as a sibling (child of parent) to the product title `td` element, using an index.

Sometimes on this page the price is wrapped within a span, which I have also accounted for below. The code is not bullet proof but I hope it will of some help anyway.

```
$url = 'http://www.iranjib.ir/showgroup/95/'
    . '%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2-'
    . '%D9%84%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%BE/';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url); // Suppress loads of warnings
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Loop product title nodes
$titleQuery = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='entry entryltr']");

for ($i = 0; $i < $titleQuery->length; $i++) {
    $titleNode = $titleQuery->item($i);
    $priceNode = $titleNode->parentNode->childNodes->item(16); // Price sibling
    $itemData['title'] = trim($titleNode->nodeValue);

    if ($priceNode) {
        // If price is within a span
        $lastPriceSpanNodeQuery = $xpath->query(
            ".//span[@class='lastprice']", $priceNode
        );

        if ($lastPriceSpanNodeQuery->length) {
            // Get price from td/span
            $priceNode = $lastPriceSpanNodeQuery->item(0);
        }
        $itemData['price'] = trim($priceNode->nodeValue);
    }

    $data[] = $itemData;
}
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => DELL XPS L502 X
            [price] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Dell 5537
            [price] => 2,048,874
        )

            ...

    [119] => Array
        (
            [title] => Lenovo G510
            [price] => 2,335,392
        )

)
```

Comment: thank's.Now How can use foreach loop instead for loop in your code? @mhall

Comment: how you find node number? item(16)  @mhall

Comment: The price is actually `td` sibling #8, but as each `td` also is followed by a
    text node, even if it is empty, you'll have to multiply that value by 2.
    To use `foreach` instead of `for`, replace `for ($i = 0; $i < $titleQuery->length; $i++) {
    $titleNode = $titleQuery->item($i);` with `foreach ($titleQuery as $titleNode) {`